# write mongodb lookup with multiple $expr to java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following lookup script :-

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "table2",
    "let": {"s_id": "$s_id","s_date": "$s_date"},
    "pipeline": [{
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {"$eq": ["$$s_id","$s_id"]},
        "$expr": {"$eq": ["$$s_date","$s_date"]}
       }
      }
     ],
   "as": "table2_values"
  }
 }
```

`$expr` value will be dynamic(on 1 field or more than 1 fields) but here i am taking 2 fields for example. I am trying to write above aggregation script to java. Could you please help me

```
List<String> whereClauseTable1List = new ArrayList<>();
whereClauseTable1List.add("s_id");
whereClauseTable1List.add("s_date");

List<String> whereClauseTable2List = new ArrayList<>();
whereClauseTable2List.add("s_id");
whereClauseTable2List.add("s_date");

 BasicDBObject letTable1Var = new BasicDBObject();
 for(String whereClauseTable1: whereClauseTable1List){
        letTable1Var.put(whereClauseTable1,"$"+whereClauseTable1);
  }

   BasicDBObject pipeLineMatchExp = new BasicDBObject();
    int index = 0;
    for(String whereClauseTable2: whereClauseTable2List){
        pipeLineMatchExp.append("$expr", new BasicDBObject("$eq", new 
        Object[]{"$$" + whereClauseTable2, "$" + 
        whereClauseTable1List.get(index)}));
        index++;
    }

  DBObject lookupDBOp = new BasicDBObject(
            "$lookup",
            new BasicDBObject("from","table2")
                    .append("let", letTable1Var)
                    .append("pipeline",new Object[]{new 
                    BasicDBObject("$match", pipeLineMatchExp)})
                    .append("as", "table2_values")
    );
```

Actually `BasicObject` does not take the duplicate key, so its always be having 1 `$expr` condition. I would like to write above script

Comment: Your `$match` expression is wrong. You cannot use the same object key of `$expr` **twice**. For this you use [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) which is an "aggregation operator" so it needs to be "inside" the *single* `$expr` key. Also which version of spring-mongo ( or even just plain Java Driver ) is this? `BasicDBObject` is not used in modern releases and replaced by `Document`. If you are using an older driver then the bigger concern is compatibility issues with modern MongoDB servers. `Document` came about before the new `$lookup` was available.

Comment: @NeilLunn Np, i can use `and` in query like this `"pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$and" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$s_date" , "$s_date"]} , { "$eq" :["$$s_id" : "$s_id"]}]}}}]`. But how to write `$eq` more than once because `BasicDBObject` doesn't allow duplicate keys. I am using `spring-boot-data-mongodb-1.5.10.RELEASE` and `mongodb-3.6.X`

Comment: Can you check your dependencies please. I don't know what `spring-boot-data-mongodb` is. There is `spring-data-mongodb` and the current releases start with `2.x`. At any rate the `$and: [ .. ]` list just a `List`, so you can usually just do a `Arrays.asList()` or similar construction for creating a list of `DBObject`. But as stated, you really should check the dependencies and update here because those all really should be `Document`, and more importantly using a modern `mongodb-java` release.

Comment: with above spring-boot version `mongodb-driver-3.4.3`  and `spring-data-mongodb-1.10.10.RELEASE`

Comment: Added into `string[]` then added using this `Arrays.asList()`. Its working thanks